# Using jQuery to determine an element's class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Most examples I can find showing how to work with attributes show how to set them and not how to retrieve them. In my case, I am trying to get the class of an  and then parse it to determine its parent value.

HTML:

```
<select class='parent' name='parent' size='10'>
    <option value='1'>Category 1 -></option>
    <option value='2'>Category 2 -></option>
</select>

<select class='child' id='child' size='10'>
    <option class='sub_1' value='5'>Custom Subcategory 1.1</option>
    <option class='sub_1' value='3'>Subcategory 1.1</option>
    <option class='sub_2' value='4'>Subcategory 2.1</option>
</select>
```

For any given option from the child list, I need to look at the class attribute, parse the name looking for the number (“sub_[n]”) and then grab the value of the option in the parent list.

My code so far (childVal has a value of “5” in my test case):

```
var class = child.find("option[value=" + childVal + "]").attr("class");
```

The above class variable is coming back “undefined.” I know the .find is working because I can use it for other things. The problem is getting at the class name.

Once I get the class name, I can strip out the “sub_” to get at the id number.

Is there a better way to do this? Why is .attr(“class”) returning undefined?

Here's a Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/n6dZp/8/ to a broken example.

Thank you,

Rick

This is the full function I am working on. It's a cascading select list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cascadeSelect(parent, child, childVal) {
        var childOptions = child.find('option:not(.static)');
        child.data('options', childOptions);

        parent.change(function () {
            childOptions.remove();
            child
                    .append(child.data('options').filter('.sub_' + this.value))
                    .change();
        })

        childOptions.not('.static, .sub_' + parent.val()).remove();

        if (childVal != '') {
            var className = child.find("option[value=" + childVal + "]").attr("class"); 

            ** need code here to select the parent and the child options based
            on childVal **
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        $('.categoryform').find('.child').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != null) {
                $('.categoryform').find('#CategoryId').val($(this).val());
            }
        });
    });

    $(function () {
        cascadeForm = $('.categoryform');
        parentSelect = cascadeForm.find('.parent');
        childSelect = cascadeForm.find('.child');

        cascadeSelect(parentSelect, childSelect, "5");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: [`class` is reserved as a future keyword by the ECMAScript spec.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the class attribute:

```
var classAttribute =  $('#child').find('option[value="' + childVal + '"]:first').attr('class');
```

To obtain the 'n' value you can parse the class attribute with a RegEx:

```
var nValue = /\bsub_([\S]*)\b/.exec( classAttribute )[1];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That seems rather over-coded -- what's wrong with `var nValue = classAttribute.replace('sub_','');`?

Comment: @lonesomeday - That's still overcoded.  I'd go with `var nValue = classAttribute.substr(4);`

Comment: I still get "undefined" on your .find example. :(

Comment: I updated my post to show the whole function. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Hi lonesomeday, lets imagine we add more classes to the element. in this case this proposal is resilient -it's not going to break up unexpectedly- that's why I suggest RegEx :)

Comment: @SDReyes That's a reasonable point.  I think you could argue this one either way...

Comment: The .find is still returning undefined. :(

Comment: No go. I updated the Fiddle example so you can see. http://jsfiddle.net/n6dZp/8/  When the page comes up, sub-category 2.1 should be selected on the right and category 2 on the left. I added an alert so you can see the results of the find. Keep in mind that I am trying to use child.find and not #child. Thanks for helping! This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Update line 12: 
'childOptions.not('.static, .sub_' + parent.val()).remove();' -> 

'childOptions.find('.static, .sub_' + parent.val()).remove();'

Comment: you were removing all the elements of the collection before applying the selector :) -I understand you want to remove just the invalid elements-. hope it helps you.

Comment: I got it working by moving the "childOptions.not('.static, .sub_' + parent.val()).remove();" after the if test. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

`class` is a reserved word in Javascript, so you can't have a variable with that name.  Try

```
var className = child.find("option[value=" + childVal + "]").attr("class");
```

Comment: Are you sure you have defined `child` (presumably as `$('#child')` and `childVal`?  I have run this code against the HTML you provide and it works as it should.

Comment: I updated my post to show the whole function. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use class as a variable name. Kills IE.

This will work but what is child variable equal to?

Comment: "child" is the child select list as represented by the html in my post.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, I didn't read your question very carefully at first.  Here's my take on what you should do:

```
var parentVal = $('.child option[value=' + childVal + ']').attr('class').substr(4);
```

**OLD ANSWER**

This should do the trick for you:

```
$(function() {
    $('#child').change(function() {  $('.parent').val($(this).children(':selected').attr('class').substr(4));
    });
});
```

Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/n6dZp/

Answer (score 0):

For a start you are missing the $

You need:

```
var class = $(".child").find("option[value=" + childVal + "]").attr("class");
```